# Parse.com - Static files vs Dynamic URLs order

Tags: express, parse-platform

I'm trying to execute cloud code first, before looking for files in the /public directory on Parse.com Cloud code.

Reading ExpressJS documentation, I've found that you can change the precedence using

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

the problem is when I try to deploy to parse, I get the following error

> Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was
>   ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined

is `__dirname` supported ?

Answer (score 0):

It would just be `express.static('public');`  however, this probably won't work.  Parse Hosting may completely skip touching/looking at cloud code for URLs under the public folder (in fact, I'm 99% sure it does.)

Comment: Hi @Fosco, please tell us how to route to static page from express app.js.

Comment: If you wanted to do what the OP is asking, you could just use non-/public routes and do an express response redirect to a /public url if you decide to serve a static resource.

Comment: I eventually ended up doing that.Thanks fr the info . I also wanted to know how to diaplay our own custom 404 error page. 

app.use(function(req, res) {
res.status(404).end('customErrorPage');
});

as per express docs i used but still parse server redirects to parse error  page. Please help