# Include css to html using express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am trying to include a css sheet to my simple html page.
I am using parse.com hosting to host a dynamic webpages that uses express.

There is a ton of answers on this questions, but none of them seemed to work for me.

I am trying to include my css file from my .ejs page with this line of code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content.css" />
```

I copyed my css folder inside the public floder

The most suggested answer is to add this line of code:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

but it did not work.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine


app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body



// This is an example of hooking up a request handler with a specific request
// path and HTTP verb using the Express routing API.

app.get('/content/:id', function(req, res) {


            res.render('content', {message: "hi"});

});
```

I am following this guide to set up express:
https://www.parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp-started

when I try to deploy my code, I get this error "Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743519/parse-com-static-files-vs-dynamic-urls-order

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this problem for some more time, I read this on parse.com website.

```
"our Express app can sit side-by-side with any static content you deployed from your public folder. When a request goes to a URL of your subdomain, Parse will first look for a matching file in the public directory. If there is no match, then Parse will invoke any Express request handlers that you have registered in Cloud Code. If there is still no match, Parse will render a "404 Not Found" page."
```